# Access a specific Shell FlyoutItem from another page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

In my AppShell.xaml.cs page I can easily access the FlyoutItems of the Shell:

```
accountFlyoutItem.IsEnabled = false;
accountFlyoutItem.IsVisible = false;
```

However, how do you access these from another page? The only way I found was to try to iterate through the "Shell.Current.FlyoutItems". Is there a simpler way I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shell.Current.CurrentItem` is used to get the current selected flyout .

If we want to access specific `FlyoutItem` after you named it in xaml (`<FlyoutItem x:Name="a">`) , we can get it from the following two ways

- Create a global public variable in `AppShell` and assign the value in constructor.

```
 public ShellItem AItem;

        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterRoutes();
            BindingContext = this;

            AItem = a;
        }
```

```
//In another page

var item = (Shell.Current as AppShell).AItem;
```

- Create a method to return the item , in this way we don't need to create the public variable .

```
   public ShellItem GetA()
        {
            return a;
        }
```

```
//In another page

var item = (Shell.Current as AppShell).GetA();
```